# How to setup QT Creator to use Autodesk FBX SDK as a library?

Tags: qt, 3d, fbx, qt3d

The Qt documentation for QMesh at the following link, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qt3drender-qmesh.html, shows that QMesh supports FBX when using the Autodesk FBX SDK. It provides no resource about how to go about setting this up, so I searched and found 1 resource on setting up the FBX SDK with Qt Creator at the following link:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fbx-forum/including-sdk-to-qt-creator/td-p/8184654

I tried the above solution, but when I try to load the QMesh I still get a Debug warning that: `Qt3D.Renderer.Jobs: unsupported format encountered (fbx)`

This is my code, which works for `.obj` files

```
Qt3DRender::QMesh* mesh = new Qt3DRender::QMesh();
mesh->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filepath));
```

I'm not sure if the "fbx geometry loader plugin is built and found" which according the Qt documentation is needed. I put the proper reference to the library in my `.pro`, but as far as I can tell `setSource` still doesn't know to utilize FBX files.

Comment: Can there be differences between `fbx` files? Or is it one uniform standard like `obj`? If the latter, then Qt3D supports loading `fbx` files out of the box. At least in my project I can open and view `fbx` files without installing any SDKs.

Comment: How do you access the skeleton and animate the mesh?

Comment: @FlorianBlume can you manipulate the mesh via it's skeleton in Qt3D with C++?

Comment: I think in order to obtain the skeleton you need load your 3D model using the `QSceneLoader` class.This probably also creates the skeleton component. If so, you should be able to manipulate the skeleton.

Comment: When I did try using the SceneLoader I was still unable to access the skeleton.