# FbxGeometryLoader with QML

Tags: qml, fbx, qt3d

I want to import a .fbx file into my [Scene3D](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtdatavisualization-scene3d.html), via the [QMesh](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qt3drender-qmesh.html) type, all in QML. Per the documentation,

> QMesh will also support the following format if the SDK is installed and the fbx geometry loader plugin is built and found

So the result I want is something like the following:

```
Entity {
... 
   Mesh{
   source: "qrc:/3dmodels/potato.fbx"
   }
}
```

After some searching, I found [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/91116/how-can-i-install-fbx-sdk-and-build-the-loader-plugins-correctly-with-qt5-10/4) post on the Qt forum, which directed me to download and include the Autodesk SDK into my project (via CMake).

I think that the only part I am lacking is to build the geometry loader for fbx, which I found in the source files (Qt/5.11.1/Src/qt3d/src/plugins/geometryloaders/fbx).

**My question:**
How do I build the fbx geomerty loader from source, and include it into my project?

Comment: Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234263/how-to-setup-qt-creator-to-use-autodesk-fbx-sdk-as-a-library) question, for me loading `fbx` files works out of the box. Did you try to simply load it?

Comment: Yes, I tried to load it (with the code posted). The same error as @karamazovbros got is outputted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned the `QSceneLoader` supports FBX loading and was able to load my FBX files with the `setSource` function, so I would use that class instead of using `QMesh`. Here's the link to the `QSceneLoader` documentation:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qt3drender-qsceneloader.html

Comment: Thank you. I seem to have run into a new problem where some of the internal properties does not load, but that is a problem for another thread.