# Accessing mesh and skeleton of FBX in Qt3D

Tags: qt, qml, fbx, qt3d

I want to expand on [myselfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276844/fbxgeometryloader-with-qml) and [karamazovbros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234263/how-to-setup-qt-creator-to-use-autodesk-fbx-sdk-as-a-library) question regarding Qt3D and import of fbx files.

I have not found any documentation on how to access the files skeleten structure. The purpose of my project is to perform animations (transforms, rotation) on various parts of the fbx file.

The fbx is dynamically loaded with a similar method as in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html), and a SceneLoader is used.

```
Entity{
..
  SceneLoader {
  source: "qrc:/3dmodels.potato.fbx"
 }
..
}
```